# Can you create an editable input field in an RDLC Report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I was wondering if there is a possibility to add an input field in the RDLC Report definition, so the user can type something before saving the the report.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer, NO

RDLC is a file that is designed to be the last part of the report cycle.

---

**BUT**, you CAN create a visual-like the report itself, with the Input that you desire, after that, the user can finish it and generate the RDLC

*Breed Crumb:* Create a page that looks like your report **=>** Add the editable input where you need **=>** Create a button in this "report" (page) **=>** Generate your ***REAL*** report.

Comment: Can you give me more information on that? as to what do you mean by more visual like report? Did you mean passing values in it?

Answer (score 2):

As [@Michel pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21587298/662581), RDLC reports are read-only, once generated.

### Another Workaround:

Have an input field in your page, plus embed your Report in a Report Viewer control, with a parameter that takes the value of the input field.

Each time the user changes the value of the input field (or presses the some refresh button) then you regenerate the Report and show it again in the Report Viewer.